# nyroModal Sizes not working for version 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, nyromodal

I have download the version 2 of nyroModal but can't ge the sizes to work. I have tried:

```
   $('.nyroModal').nyroModal(
    {
        sizes:
        {
             w: 300,
             h: 300
        }
    });
```

And also this:

```
    $.nmObj(
    {
            sizes:
            {
                 w: 300,
                 h: 300
            }
    });

    $('.nyroModal').nyroModal();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```js
<input type="button" value="show Pop" onclick="ShowPop("pop.htm",300,280);">

function ShowPop(url,width,height){
   $.nmManual(url, {
        callbacks: {
            afterShowCont: function (nm) {
                alert(nm.elts.cont);
                nm.sizes.initW = width;
                nm.sizes.initH = height;
                nm.resize(true);
            }
        }
});
}
```

this work fine in my project, hope this would help you.
Is this make sense now.
parameter url is the path of the popup window. using the callback and filter afterShowCont to resize the popup window.

Comment: perhaps you could add a few sentences explaining how your code sample works?